# Android Studio Not Detecting Kindle Fire HD Tablet

Tags: android, android-studio, kindle-fire

I followed all of Amazon's instructions (https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/01-setting-up-your-development-environment), but my Kindle Fire HD (2013 model) tablet is not showing up in Android Studio when I try to run an app. It works fine on another computer in Android Studio, but not on this one (I recently reinstalled Windows 8.1 and Android Studio 1.3.2).

To clarify: I don't see it in the device list under 'Choose a running device'.

Answer (score 2):

Change the cable ? Sometimes if you are not using a stock cable or one designed for transfer of information it will do nothing when plugged in.

or

May need to change the adb_usb.ini to include your device signature text.

Or

It is your USB drivers for the tablet.

Or

You have not gone into developer settings and enabled developer mode.

If you have found this useful, please do not forget to vote UP :)

Answer (score 2):

My apologies. I couldn't see properly, so I mistakenly skipped the instruction to run KindleDrivers.exe

It's working now. :)